# Integrating paypal with c++ MFC app

Tags: c++, mfc, paypal-rest-sdk

We are planning to integrate Paypal with one of our cpp application written using MFC. The question is shall we use Rest apis to accomplish this? or there is any other easier way to do achieve this? I have recently used  Paypal REST Services via Postman and they look pretty easy. What I want to achieve is how can I use rest apis for paypal without launching the browser ? How can I achieve Login credentials from the user ? Can anyone point me to right direction ? 
Appreciate your help in advance.
Thanks 
AJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using PayPal REST API https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/ as they putting more effort into it. There is also SOAP API, but I would not use it. It seems like dated.

You can use ultra modern **Casablanca C++ REST SDK** which is an open source framework from Microsoft available at: https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk to implement your end-point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you also have idea how to hanlde the login feature into paypal before the user wanted to pay ? Shall we produce a login page locally as we are planning to avoid browser. If in case we create our own Login page will we need to get PCI complaint app ?

Comment: I would definitely implement login form/window locally as `CDialog`-derived class for example. And yes you need to make sure that the application meet PCI DSS Requirements.

Comment: Thanks Andrew and it looks like too much of extra work, instead will launch the web browser within the app and use rest api's where will show paypal's login page and everything there after. The only question here I have is will how will know from the webpage that the payment has been made as I am not planning to create my own server, basically how can I handle events from paypal into my app. Any idea ? And will i be still need to make the app pci complaint ?

Comment: You can call javascript functions directly from `CHtmlView`. So I don't see any issues/problems here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using [Wizdome](https://www.securedglobe.net/wizdome) which is c++ / MFC oriented. A product named [Datattoo recovery](http://www.datattoo.com) developed under c++ and MFC allows paying for the amount of data successfully recovered, and the integration with PayPal is done that way.
Here is a [more detailed](https://securedglobe.wordpress.com/2017/03/27/flawless-integration-with-paypal/) description about the process: